# Display "and X more" after limit is reached in join

Tags: php

I have a table with likes for a post, and I want to display the users that liked it. What I'm going for is for it to show up to the first 5 people, and after that it should show `and X more people liked this post`. I also be able to get the remaining users in an array and not just have the amount of them.

```
$array = array();

foreach($this->forums_model->get_topic_likes($top->id) as $likes) { 
    $array[] = "<a href=''>" . $this->user_model->get_username($likes["user_id"]) . "</a>";
}

$count = $this->forums_model->count_topic_likes($top->id);
echo join(' and ', array_filter(array_merge(array(join(', ', array_slice($array, 0, ($count - 2)))), array($count - 5 . " more people like this post")), 'strlen'));
```

This doesn't exactly work like I want it to, and was wondering how this could be achieved.

Answer (score 0):

Select all likes in an array and then only show the first 5 and display array.length - 5 as the remaining count.